# Validating empty space in class validator

Tags: node.js, typeorm, class-validator

I want to validate the Address field, it may contain numbers or strings, but it should not accept continuous empty spaces

```
@IsAlphaNumeric()
Address: string;
```

I want the Address to be numeric or alphabetic
but it should not accept continuous empty spaces

Answer (score 35):

An alternative solution without custom validation decorators would be:

```
@IsNotEmpty()
@Transform(({ value }: TransformFnParams) => value?.trim())
Address: string;
```

Comment: the `.trim()` might crash if the `value` variable is null, undefined or any other type other than string. Should add an "optional chaining" like @razouq did in his answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69595889/12056841

Comment: Thanks @ShaniKehati, you are correct without it, it crashed. Please edit the answer

Comment: @Markus what is the TransformFnParams ? where can I import that?

Comment: @huykon225 `import { TransformFnParams } from 'class-transformer';`

Comment: About usage of "optional chaining" necessity, is this still valid? I have tried with/without IsNotEmpty, if value is undefined, Transform cb never called?  @ShaniKehati

Comment: @CanerSezgin https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/blob/2ef8ff0f32be53e75dade2a0b86b158d87427176/src/decorator/common/IsNotEmpty.ts#L10 
You might be correct, but, I won't rely on that- I would still make sure to check that the variable in `@Transform` decorator can be `trim`ed. **The best** would be to check `typeof value==="string"?value.trim():""`

Comment: @ShaniKehati your solution doesn't work with me

Comment: Hi, I added type-validation suggestion to the given answer, can I help you with something? What doesn't work? @esraa

Comment: I agree with Shani. In the case of a number, for example, optional chaining will not prevent the trim() method from being called on it, which will lead to a crash.

Answer (score 18):

Afaik there's no support for a "isNotBlank"-decorator, but you can just write one yourself:

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationOptions } from "class-validator";

export function IsNotBlank(property: string, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
    return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
        registerDecorator({
            name: "isNotBlank",
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName: propertyName,
            constraints: [property],
            options: validationOptions,
            validator: {
                validate(value: any) {
                    return typeof value === "string" && value.trim().length > 0;
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
```

You would then add this custom validator to your existing one:

```
@IsNotBlank()
@IsAlphaNumeric()
Address: string;
```

Checkout https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators for more information regarding custom validators.

Comment: there is no validator called @IsNotBlank in calss validator

Comment: that is what he has written, that you have to create your own decorator and register it with your code and then you can use it

Answer (score 3):

```
@IsNotEmpty()
@Transform((({value}): string) => value?.trim())
Address: string;
```

destructure the 'value' after that you can trim it

Comment: you shouldn't assign the `string` type to the `value` variable because it could be anything. Should just follow the `TransformFnParams` type. just like @Markus suggested in his answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64842927/12056841

Answer (score 2):

You can use the the `@NotContains` class validator. DTO should like this:

```js
@IsAlphaNUmereic()
@NotContains(" ")
address: string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to validate your key:
Import the required properties:

```
import { IsNotEmpty,Length,NotContains } from "class-validator";
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";
```

Create a class for the payload:

```
export class SomePayloadCheckDto {
  @ApiProperty({ required: true })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @NotContains(" ")
  @Transform(({ value }) => value?.trim())
  @Length(3, 20)
  someString: string;
}
```